# IContent and IPublishedContent return null for the other tabs properties

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am having two tabs in the page. when I trying to access the properties using IContent and IPublishedContent, I am able to access the properties of the first tab but for second tab property its returning null.

Can anyone suggest how I should I access my second tab properties while iterating?

// Getting null for the second tab property

```
foreach (IContent local in localsNode.Children())
{
    var questionInsight = local.Properties["questioninsight"].Value.ToString();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: your second tab don't seem like a property, more of a list to me.  If it is list then you should get it through `Children`.  If not, then is that a custom datatype?

Comment: @AlanTsai: It's a separate tab in document type "question" however its contains the list view of other "insights" form, if you have any code sample to access it please share it...

Comment: @AlanTsai: I am able to access it using the Children, thank you very much for your suggestion...

Comment: glad you got it sorted.  For the sake of future googler, I have added comment as answer to the question, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a custom data type, you can access list content via the `Children` property.

list item in umbraco are just children under current node